# Maintain float precision when selecting values in a pandas dataframe using iloc

Tags: python, pandas

My code:

```
import pandas as pd 

pd.set_option('display.float_format','{:.2f}'.format)

df = pd.Series([500.0, 200.0, 300.0])
df
0   500.00
1   200.00
2   300.00
dtype: float64

df.iloc[1]
200.0
```

I want `df.iloc[1]` to return 200.00, can anyone explain what's happening here and how to get the desired result please.

Comment: once you do `df.iloc[1]`, you get a float, and it's no longer up to `pandas` to format this number. You may want to use `format` function.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang using format did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

Indexing the way you did will return the actual value at that index, which is type float.

```
type(df.iloc[1]) # returns 'numpy.float64'
```

What you would like to do is print the entire row, like so:

```
df.iloc[[1]]
```

In this case, the index returns a series:

```
type(df.iloc[[1]]) # returns 'pandas.core.series.Series'
```